# Is it possible to only retrieve unique values from a document in mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm guessing the answer is no, but is this possible?  It seems like this is too much code for something so simple:

```
ary = []
obj.all.each {|o| ary << o[:foo]}
ary.uniq!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate from Mongo, you can write that same functionality in Ruby better as:

```ruby
ary = obj.all.map{ |o| o[:foo] }.uniq
```

**Edit**: It looks like Mongo supports this via `distinct`:

```
ary = @db['pageviews'].distinct('ip-address')
```

See [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I am using mongoid and guess I should skip to the mongo documentation for certain queries.

Comment: @Jeremy Here is the [MongoID documentation for `distinct`](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Contexts/Mongo#distinct-instance_method)